# MYSQL Select Statement with IN Clause and Multiple Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

There might be an easy solution here, but it seems to have me tripped up.  I'm trying to query a table based on an array of values in two columns. Here is the pertinent table structure and sample data

```
comment table
id, userId, articleId .... etc etc

article table
id, userId .... etc etc

Data:  UserIds = 3, 10.   ArticleIds = 1, 2
```

Let's say I'm trying to find all the comments for a particular set of article IDs:  1,2

I can easily use this query

```
select * from comments WHERE articleId IN(1,2)
```

However, here is where it gets complex.  I have a query that executes prior to the comments query that determines the appropriate article IDs.  Those IDs are in an array.  Also in an array are the corresponding user IDs for each article.

What I want to do now is query the comments table for only the articles in the array (1,2) AND only for those comments made by the original author (3, 10).

The simple query above will bring back all the comments for articleId 1 and 20.  So for example I can't figure out where to add another conditional that says onyl comments for articleId 1, 20 AND corresponding userId, 3, 10.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I your array a PHP array or MySql array?

Comment: I think the HAVING clause might be able to help you out here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: maybe it's not an elegant way but one solution would be to concat the values using a separator. that if you want article 1 and author 3 or article 2 and author 10 (and not article 1 and author 10).. meaning `CONCAT(userId, '_', articleId) IN ('1_3', '2_10')` ..

Comment: @sabre The HAVING clause looks interesting. I hadn't even considered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to write:

```
SELECT comments.*
  FROM articles
  JOIN comments
    ON articles.id = comments.articleId
   AND articles.userId = comments.userId
 WHERE articles.id IN (1, 2)
;
```

The `AND articles.userId = comments.userId` clause is what enforces your "only for those comments made by the original author" requirement.

Alternatively, you can use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT *
  FROM comments
 WHERE articleId IN (1, 2)
   AND EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM articles
           WHERE id = comments.articleId
             AND userId = comments.userId
        )
;
```

or a single-row subquery:

```
SELECT *
  FROM comments
 WHERE articleId IN (1, 2)
   AND userId =
        ( SELECT userId
            FROM articles
           WHERE id = comments.articleId
        )
;
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works exactly as I wanted it to.  I'm running some tests to make sure, but I've run a number of different combinations and they all return the appropriate data.  I really appreciate the quick response.  I'm going to run a couple more tests then I'll mark your answer as correct.  Quick question ... are either of the other 2 queries you reference above any more or less efficient?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @K_C: The only way to definitively resolve a performance question is to try both ways -- all of these queries return the exact same results, so they're drop-in replacements and you can directly compare them -- but I would bet that the `JOIN` approach is the fastest. From what I've read, MySQL is not very good at optimizing correlated subqueries (`(SELECT ...)` subexpressions that refer to fields in the outer query), which both of the latter queries require.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try the others as well, but your first is perfect!  Marking it as the answer.  Thanks again to you (and everyone else too) for the incredible quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just

```
select * from comments WHERE articleId IN(1,2) and authorId in (3,10)
```

If not, please update your question why it's so.

Comment: That wouldn't satisfy the "only for those comments made by the original author" requirement: it would return all comments by *either* user to *either* article, rather than only returning the comments made by each user to his/her *own* article.

Comment: Ok, please post the database structure than.

Comment: @john - I thought your suggestion was the way to go, but I actually need to make sure that I'm only returning comments from the original author.  So comments from authorID =3 to articleId = 1.   I apologize if I wasn't clear. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many `IN` statements as you want:

```
select * from comments WHERE articleId IN(1,2) AND userId IN (3,10)
```

Comment: @gavincattell - I thought your solution was going to work, but I think I wasn't clear in my post.  I'm looking for only comments made by authorId=3 for articleId=1.  Or authorId=10 and articleId=2.  I really appreciate the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make the query that runs first a subquery within your stated query:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleId` IN(1,2) AND `userId` IN (__subquery__)
```

Answer (score 0):

-- you can use subquery

```
select * from comments WHERE articleId IN(1,2)
and userId in ( select userId from article where id in (1,2) )
```